# Excel Function to count a given value across two columns, where it counts if the value is in one column or both

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to develop an excel formula which will return a value which is a count of the number of rows which contain the term ‘Yes’, as shown in the table below, where for A1:B4 it should return 3.

```
-|A —|B— |  
1|Yes|—— |
2|Yes|Yes|
3|—- |—- |
4|—- |Yes|
```

Comment: `=SUM(--(LEFT(A1:A4&B1:B4)="Y"))` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$B$4="Yes"))-SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4&$B$1:$B$4="YesYes"))
```

You can use SUMPRODUCT to count how many single *Yes* values you got and then subtract the *double Yes* values.

Other options:

`=COUNTIF($A$1:$B$4;"Yes")-COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4;"Yes";$B$1:$B$4;"Yes")`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4&$B$1:$B$4={"Yes-";"-Yes";"YesYes"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a helper column, based on `=IF(OR(A1="Yes",B1="Yes),1,0)`, this generates 1 if there is a "Yes" and 0 otherwise. All what's left is taking the sum of that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((A1:A15="Yes")+(B1:B15="Yes"))>0))
```

Or below formula with ***O365***.

```
=SUM(--(BYROW(A1:B11,LAMBDA(x,OR(x="Yes")))))
```

[image]